# Groovy tests runned by maven doesn't display non ASCI symbols

Tags: maven, groovy, gmaven-plugin

I'm using gmaven plugin to compile sources. I have got following configuration file

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
            <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <providerSelection>1.7</providerSelection>
                <sourceEncoding>UTF-8</sourceEncoding>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generateStubs</goal>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>generateTestStubs</goal>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
</plugin>
```

If I run `mvn clean install` non ASCI symbols will be displayed as `? �`. How can I solve it?

Comment: I assume the terminal/cli you are using can display these characters normally?

Comment: Yes, Intellij Idea runs this tests and display characters correctly (if I run them as JUnit tests)